# Whats the difference between "${foo.bar}" and "#{foo.bar}"?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I can use objects from my Java Beans within .jsp files by using the Expression Language (EL). Therefore I can get my value by typing ${foo.bar}. But I can also use #{foo.bar}.

Can anybody explain the difference or provide a link with meaningful information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#{foo.bar}` syntax is from the JSF expression language. Some bright spark thought it would be a good idea to use a different syntax to JSP EL (i.e. `${foo.bar}`). I think some JSP containers are tolerant of this cockup, and let you use either one.

Comment: So I could use ${...} anytime I want and #{...} only in case of using JSF which means that #{...} has the same functionality... That really must have been a bright spark :D
Thanks ;)

Comment: JSF was a ghastly mess from day one, and they've been trying to paper over the cracks ever since.

Comment: Ok... but why is it a mess? I'm new to it, therefore I haven't much experience with it ;)

Comment: Downvoted! not the slightest mention to immediate/deferreed evaluation, as clearly explained in the javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el002.htm#BNAHR, at least explain why is it a bad idea...

Answer (score 17):

This is covered in the [JSP 2.1 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/index.html).

In Java EE, `#{expr}` is used for *deferred evaluation* and `${expr}` for *immediate evaluation*. Deferred expressions (`#{expr}`) expressions can only be used with tag attributes that accept them. This is a Java EE convention, but other domains could impose their own meaning (e.g. if you wanted to [use EL in your own templates](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/04/java-using-el-outside-j2ee.html)).

Comment: Aha, interesting, I wasn't aware of that. +1